# Create new image element using the src of image in another div using jquery

Tags: jquery, src, attr

```
<div id='show-image'></div>
<div class='post'>
<div class='inner'>
<img class='post-img' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Sg5t3utxRzc/UwgyzbLVAAI/AAAAAAAAFBo/vYQX0Cphx8U/s1600/indian-bride.jpg'/>
</div>
</div>
```

Okay so what I want is that I want to get the src of the image .post-img and want to create a new image element inside the div id='show-image'

I would be glad if anyone can help me to achieve this using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get the `src` of your image then **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** to append newly created image with retrieved `src` to the div with id `show-image`:

```
var src = $('.post-img').attr('src');
$('#show-image').append('<img src="' + src + '" />');
```

or you can use **[.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)**:

```
var url=$('.post-img').attr("src"); 
$('<img src="'+url+'" />').appendTo('#show-image');
```

Comment: Hi! felix I'm bothering you again but I want to know that same condition is applicable if img tag is replaced by iframe.

Answer (score 1):

---

Just another way of writing it

```
var newImg = $("<img>", { 
                src: $(".post-img").attr("src") 
            });
$("#show-image").append(newImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var img = $('<img>');
img.attr('src', $("img.post-img").attr("src"));
img.appendTo('#show-image');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9n77/)**